# How to find the inverse $y=|x|^2x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

How to find the invere $y(x)=|x|^2x$ where $x$ is a vector in $R^n$ . I know that $|x|^2=x\circ x$ so i try to manipulate multiply in both side for $y\circ x= |x|^2x\circ x=|x|^4$, but how to find $x$ in terms of $y$, can somebody give me a hint about how to continued please? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \neq 0$. Then $|y|=|x|^{2}|x|=|x|^{3}$ so $|x|=|y|^{1/3}$. Hence $x=\frac y {|x|^{2}}=\frac y {|y|^{2/3}}$. Note that $x=0$ iff $y=0$ so the inverse map sends $0$ to $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much..terrific